# logic confusion with rand() in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, random

I'm trying to do skip-list insertion, so I'm using rand() to determine the level. I know I need to do continuous coin flips, so I figure if I print test counts for the generator it should have approximately 50% less for each successive level. I'm messing up with the logic somehow, but I can't catch my mistake. On the last level it is ~== to the level before it, instead of half.

Here's my code:

```
#define MAXLEVEL 5
srand(time(NULL));
int newLevel;
int a[6] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {      
    for (newLevel = 0; (rand() < RAND_MAX/2) && (newLevel < MAXLEVEL); newLevel++);
    a[newLevel]++;
}
printf("0: %d   1: %d   2: %d   3: %d   4: %d   5: %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
```

And here's the output:

```
0: 50018   1: 24969   2: 12532   3: 6334   4: 3094   5: 3053
```

I'm sort of expecting my mistake to be something silly, but I've been looking at this for a while now and can't seem to catch it.

Comment: `newLevel <= MAXLEVEL`

Comment: Hmmm, my book actually has `<` too, I guess this is a typo? edit: If I change it to `<=` I get `ABORT TRAP (6)`, but values that look correct.

Comment: You get the abort trap because you're writing off the end of the array. Change `int a[6]` to `int a[7]` if you want to use `newlevel <= MAXLEVEL`

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice semicolon in for loop.

Comment: I only want there to be [0:5] levels though. I could sort of fake it by using `<=` then doing `if (newLevel < MAXLEVEL) a[newLevel]++;`, but then I don't even understand why I need to do this or why it wasn't working originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we made it to level `i`. Chances that we promote to next level are ~0.5. This means that if we made it to `i`-th level `N` times, then ~0.5*N times we stop at level `i` and ~0.5*N times we promote to next level. Equivalently, we stop at level `i` ~0.5*N times and *sum* of all further level values is also ~0.5*N. Hence, last two levels have similar values no matter how many there are total levels.

Sequence of X, X/2, X/4, X/8, X/16, X/16 is expected. If you want last member to be X/32, simply add artificial level.

Comment: To be honest I'm having trouble following this. I don't understand the point you are making about sum of further levels, or why the `i`th level is different than the `i-1`th level. Also, does this mean that a skip-list which is using this code for level determination is actually doing it wrong?

Comment: My point is that it is expected for above algorithm to produce similar values at last two levels. Whether it is correct or not -- I can't answer without reading book you have. But my guess is that this skip-list is supposed to have only 5 true levels, 0 to 4. Level number 5 is artificial.